# Network Error While Uploading Large File

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, file-upload, upload

```
Network Error (tcp_error) 
A communication error occurred: "Can't send more"
```

The error occured when uploading large file (e.g. 200MB). I have already changed following settings:

> upload_max_filesize = 300M
>
> post_max_size = 2G
>
> max_execution_time = 86400
>
> max_file_uploads = 40
>
> memory_limit = 300M
>
> FcgidMaxRequestLen = 1677721600

What else should I change?

Comment: I have already looked through error_log, but there is no error on this process

Answer (score 0):

you better try a chunked upload. Transferring big content will probably fail

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads

Comment: Nagy Zoltan, should I first setup this plugin or you mean I can use some part of these codes?